# Midi event routing on Android

Tags: java, android, midi

I'm a newbie to Android programming and try to modify mediaplayer.start() API to clone the midi message and sent them to external midi device thru Android usb interface. It's like to show the photo or video on Android's display and TV at the same time

The goal is to sent the midi message to the Android API and external midi device at the same time. However, I don't know what API provide the function aforementioned.

In windows pc, Midi-ox and Midi-Yoke provide one midi in to two midi out port function

I've check https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver and BlueTooth solution from Mr.Peter Brinkmann but still need some inspiration to fill the gap. Maybe there is other approach to do the same. Your suggestion would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The media player handles MIDI internally. Android does not have MIDI APIs.

Comment: Hi CL,Thanks for your comment, I did some homework and found that working on the mediaplayer is not a good idea so I turn to OPENSL instead.

Answer (score -1):

Test the Grand Piano in Google Play with the URL below
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.als.grandpiano.pro&hl=zh_TW
and the result is awesome, it triggers the external midi device and play midi file without latency
the sound font fully utilize the sound chip on board.

If low latency midi solution is needed, Opensl would be a good choice

Comment: OpenSL ES for Android does not support MIDI